# Jedit: regular expression - how to?

Tags: regex, jedit

It have source code that contains sections like this:

```
<pre>  text
</pre>

long long text

<pre>  text
</pre>

long long text
```

I have to find this entry

```
<pre>  text
</pre>
```

in JEdit and replace it with space. (I read the [regex rules](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/regexps.html) in the JEdit documentation.)

My expression is:

```
<pre>([\.\n]*?)</pre>
```

But it couldn't find the entry.

What expression should be correct?

Comment: This free tool very useful for debugging regex http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your regex the `.` is being treated literally and not as a meta-character to match any character except newline.

Try:

```
<pre>(.|\n)*?</pre>
```

Since the OS is not specified, a newline can be represented by either a `\n` (Unixes) or a `\r\n` (windows). In either case you can use:

```
<pre>(.|\r?\n)*?</pre>
```

Comment: +1 for your explanation. One tiny issue, I would add `\r` to the alternation, because you don't know what the newline character is (or do you?)

Comment: @stema: You are right, the existing solution will not work for Windows.

Comment: Alternatively to `\r?\n` you can use `\R`.